# How to access params body of a webhook post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I'm trying to send myself an email with the details of a post request received from a webhook

```
p = params.permit!
selfMailer.send_myself_an_email(p).deliver_later
```

However this only send me an email with the content:

```
{"controller"=>"custom/send", "action"=>"create"}
```

I tried to call `.inspect` on the params but not much changed, this is what I got:

```
"#<ActionController::Parameters {\"controller\"=>\"custom/send\", \"action\"=>\"create\"} permitted: true>"
```

In the log I can see clearly the parameters passed, there are many, but above is all I get! so how can I access them?

Comment: You can keep a debugger at "p = params.permit!" and check if you are sending correct data.

Comment: @SachinSingh after debugging my controller action I found the same value in p as what I received in the email!

Answer (score 0):

wow! I haven't thought about it, it seems that I made my app to redirect [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to example.com, so basically when the webhook request arrived to the www url it was redirected, that's why I wasn't seeing the post params!

I just adjusted the webhook url by removing the www and now it's working